# Flutter: flutter_sound package can't be initialised

Tags: flutter, pubspec

I wan't to use the flutter_sound package. After I set it up (this was already a pain), I wanted to initialise the `FlutterSoundRecorder()`. But when I start my App, I instantly get an error. I do not have much more to say. Maybe you have an idea? Thank you.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay! I can't guarantee that this will work, but try adding the keyword late in front of FlutterSoundRecorder? _player;

So the code should look like this:

```
late FlutterSoundRecorder? player;
```